# How to pull data from an outside API using EmberJS?

Tags: ajax, api, http, ember.js, get

So I'm trying to learn EmberJS, and I'm struggling really hard with this one. Basically, I have the following basic structure

**Template:**

```
<ul>
  {{#each model as |game|}}
    <li>{{game.title}} - {{game.console}}</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

**Route File:**

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model() {
        return [
         {'title':'Super Mario Bros', 'console':'NES'},
         {'title':'Pac Man', 'console':'Arcade'},
         {'title':'Galaga', 'console':'Arcade'},
         {'title':'Frogger', 'console':'Arcade'},
         {'title':'Marvel vs. Capcom', 'console':'Arcade'},
         {'title':'The Legend of Zelda', 'console':'NES'},
         {'title':'CastleVania', 'console':'NES'},
         {'title':'Final Fantasy IV', 'console':'SNES'}];
    }
});
```

But instead of just hardcoding it like I have here, I want to pull it from an Apiary API link using a GET call. How do I do I do this?

(Apiary https://private-9c66cc-managementconsole.apiary-mock.com/getactiveroms)

Answer (score 0):

For a JSON compliant API, you can do something like this:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    let url = 'https://private-9c66cc-managementconsole.apiary-mock.com/getactiveroms';
    return Ember.$.getJSON(url);
  },
});
```

However, because this API does not respond with valid JSON, you'll to fetch the API as text and manipulate the response prior to parsing it as JSON.

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    let url = 'https://private-9c66cc-managementconsole.apiary-mock.com/getactiveroms';
    return Ember.$.ajax({
      url: url,
      dataType: 'text',
    })
    .then((result) => { 
      result = result.replace(/[ \n]+/g, '');
      result = result.substring(1, result.length - 1);
      result = result.replace(/'/g, '"');
      return JSON.parse(result);
    }, (err) => {
      console.log('err', err); 
    });
  },
});
```

I suggest updating the API response to contain valid JSON to make your life easier when consuming it.